# Pass Arguments to fragment again from ViewPager on notifyDataSetChanged

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm new to Android and not sure if this is a sensible question to ask, so apologies in advance. I have been stuck at this problem for past few hours and still no luck.

I have a `viewpager` with 2 `fragments` & `FragmentPagerAdapter`. Both fragments fetch data from database based on ID value passed from activity (which has viewpager). The first time the viewpager creates fragments, I send that ID value as Bundle with the fragment with method `setArguments(bundle)` in `getItem()` *(over-rode this method in adapter class)*.

I have button on ActionBar that onClick updates value of ID in the activity,updates the value of ID in FragmentPagerAdapter class, & calls `notifyDataSetChanged` for recreating all fragments. **The problem is that the ID which I sent as Argument first time that's not updated and because of that the data in fragments is not update since that fetches from DB based on ID value.**

**What's the best way for updating the Arguments in fragments again when  `notifyDataSetChanged` is called ?**

Kindly help me with appropriate solution. Thankyou in advance.

Following are the relevant code extracts for 3 classes:

---

**in Activity class:**

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
switch (item.getItemId()) {

// Actionbar menu has NEXT menu option.
case R.id.next:
    {
        id++;   //ID is the variable that's value is to be passed
        mAdapter.setValue(id);    //mAdapter is object of PagerAdapter class that extends FragmentPagerAdapter 

        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        invalidateOptionsMenu();
        break;
    }
```

**in PagerAdapter class**

```
public void setValue(String id) {  //setter function for setting ID value
    this.id = id;
}


//this is where first time arguments are passed to fragments
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int index) {

    switch (index) {
    case 0:
    {
        // Main Abstract Content Fragment
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("id", id);

        AbstractContentTabFragment y = new AbstractContentTabFragment();
        y.setArguments(bundle);
        return y;
    }   

    return null;
}


//I had to override this because I needed to re-create all fragments
@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return POSITION_NONE;
}
```

**in Fragment class:**

```
//this is how id value is updated in fragment class
id = getArguments().getString("value");
```

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue, have you solved somehow?